# Python: show type inheritance

Tags: python, python-3.x, object

I'm trying to look under the hood in idle to wrap my head around python custom classes and how they are stored in memory. Suppose I have the following code:

```
class Point: 
    pass
x=Point()
print(x)
```

Given the following output:

> `<__main__.Point object at 0x000002A3A071DF60>`

I know that since my class consists of no code, when I create an object of type `Point`, an object of type `object` is implicitly created from which the `Point` object `x` inherits such methods as `__str__` etc. However, I cant seem to see the connection ie. when I type `dir(x)`, I dont see any attribute that stores a reference to an object of type `object`. Am I misunderstanding how it works or is there some attribute that I am unaware of?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no (direct) *instance* of type `object` involved. When you call `Point()`, a `Point` instance is created, and nothing else. Inheritance is a mechanism that operates on *classes*, not on *instances*.

Python objects have two properties: Their *type* and their *value*. The *type* of `x` is `Point`. The *value* of `x` is represented by its `__dict__`, which is empty (because it has no attributes):

```
>>> type(x)
<class '__main__.Point'>
>>> x.__dict__
{}
```

There is no reference to an `object` instance, because no such instance exists. The inheritance from `object` manifests in the *class* `Point`:

```
>>> Point.__base__
<class 'object'>
>>> Point.mro()
[<class '__main__.Point'>, <class 'object'>]
```

So the reason why `x` can use `object` methods is because `Point` inherits from `object`, not because there's a hidden `object` instance stored in `x`. You can see that `Point` has access to all `object` methods:

```
>>> Point.__str__ is object.__str__
True
>>> Point.__init__ is object.__init__
True
# etc...
```

So, by proxy, `x` has access to all `object` methods as well.

Answer (score 0):

you may be looking for `Point.__mro__`? the [method resolution order](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=__mro__#class.__mro__) of the class `Point`. it tells you in what order python will go looking for methods if you call `x.method`. in your case this will be:

```
print(Point.__mro__)  # or Point.mro()
# (<class '__main__.Point'>, <class 'object'>)
```